# How to use delegate method for more than two associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, delegation

Let's say that I'm retrieving the name of the sport by calling the following chain of associations:

```
pick.event.league.sport.name
```

How can I use the [delegate method](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) so that I can just call *pick.event_league_sport_name* like so?  Obviously, I can create a method in the pick model:

```
def event_league_sport_name
     return self.event.league.sport.name
end
```

But I want to use the [delegate method](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate)!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
class Pick
  def sport
    event.league.sport
  end

  delegate :name, :to => :sport
end
```

This would result in `pick.name` being equivalent to `pick.event.league.sport.name`.

Answer (score 14):

I dont suggest this , but if you want ...

```
delegate :name , :to => "event.league.sport" ,:prefix=>"event_league_sport"
```

also without prefix.

be sure to handle nil associations ...

have a nice day!